# How to create shortcuts on Android O, when targetting less than it?

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut, android-8.0-oreo

### Background

Android O has various changes of how shortcuts work:

https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#as

### The problem

According to recent changes on Android O, the broadcast intent to create shortcuts is completely ignored :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT
https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#as

> The com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT broadcast no longer
>   has any effect on your app, because it is now a private, implicit
>   broadcast. Instead, you should create an app shortcut by using the
>   requestPinShortcut() method from the ShortcutManager class.

This means this code, for example, won't work anymore, no matter which app you've made or which launcher the user has:

```
private void addShortcut(@NonNull final Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent().putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN))
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Currently, even the Play Store itself fails to create shortcuts to apps (at least in the current version: 80795200 ) . It just doesn't do anything, even to Google's launcher.

### The question

While I'm very against this change of API (and wrote about it [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62973732), [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62544695)) and [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62544695), I'd like to know what would it take to still make it work.

I know there is an API for this, using [**requestPinShortcut**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#requestPinShortcut(android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo,%20android.content.IntentSender)), but this requires the app to target Android O, which means a lot more changes have to be made to make sure the app works there.

My question is:
Suppose your app targets Android API 25, how do you create shortcuts on Android O ? Is it possible by using reflection of the newer API ? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this area of Android, but is there a way to have a BroadcastReceiver that checks if an app has been installed? If you can do that with a BroadcastReceiver, your launcher would be notified of the new install and then you could create the shortcut later by checking what has been installed

Comment: @LunarWatcher The question is not about a launcher. It's about other apps putting a shortcut on the launcher. The previous API allowed to request the launcher to put a shortcut to any app. Now it won't do anything, as launchers won't receive this intent anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way is to call `requestPinShortcut` method. You don't need to target android O but you need to have at least compile SDK to 26. Compile SDK and target SDK are two different things.

Comment: I see. What happens though in case the installed default launcher wasn't updated to handle this new API ? Will it still work?

Comment: It's another question and stackoverlow is not forum. Ask another question about launchers.

Comment: I asked if it will work. I don't ask for how to make it work on those launchers. Also, can you please post a sample code? The current one of the docs doesn't work for me, as it requires parameters for ShortcutInfo.Builder , and there are none in Google's docs : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html

Comment: No, it won't work. Indeed you need to call isRequestPinShortcutSupported method to check if the launcher is supporting this feature.

Comment: "the launcher" ? So I guess this also only works for the current one... ok. Why does ShortcutInfo.Builder have an id? I've set it to be just the package name and it works fine...

Comment: Hi @greywolf82. I get return false value when check this method isRequestPinShortcutSupported on Launcher2(Customized based on our requirement). My question is used to ShortcutManager.requestPinShortcut() or ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT is possible to create application shortcut with launcher2 in AOSP 10?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like I beat on this forever, but...

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
    ...
}
else {
    ShortcutManager shortcutManager
        = c.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
    if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
            c.getApplicationContext(), c.getClass());
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        ShortcutInfo pinShortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfo
            .Builder(c,"pinned-shortcut")
            .setIcon(
                Icon.createWithResource(c, R.drawable.qmark)
            )
            .setIntent(intent)
            .setShortLabel(c.getString(R.string.app_label))
            .build();
        Intent pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent = shortcutManager
            .createShortcutResultIntent(pinShortcutInfo);
        //Get notified when a shortcut is pinned successfully//
        PendingIntent successCallback
            = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                c, 0
                , pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent, 0
            );
        shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(
            pinShortcutInfo, successCallback.getIntentSender()
        );
    }
}
```

Is working for me.  I know there were changes in 7.1 and don't know if this works for them and I don't know about the launcher issues mentioned above.
This was tested on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 running Android 8.0.0.

I put a simple app that does nothing but install a shortcut for itself on your homepage on [github](https://github.com/bebop-001/CreateAppHomeShortcut).  It works for versions before and after Android 8.  Pre Android 8 uses the sendBroadcast method and after creats a pinned shortcut.