# android api 26+ create shortcut to app at install on home screen not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to get rid of the warnings that EXTRA_SHORTCUT... is deprecated from API 26 forward.  My code seems to work but the icon isn't happening on the home page.

```
private void installShortcut(Context c) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
        c.getApplicationContext(), c.getClass());
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        ShortcutInfo shortcutInfo
            = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(c, "shortcutID")
                .setShortLabel(appName)
                .setIcon(
                   createWithResource(
                      c, R.drawable.qmark))
                .setIntent(intent)
                .build();
        ShortcutManager sm 
             = c.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
        sm.createShortcutResultIntent(shortcutInfo);
    }
    else ...
```

I can step through the code with the debugger and everything seems to work.  I'm not seeing any warnings on log cat.  And I can't find any current answers to this question.

Thanks
Steve S.

Comment: Are static shortcuts working in your code?

Comment: Hi @SagarBhatnagar.  Please see my reply below.  On my device nothing happens from API 26 -- no error, no warning, no shortcut.  You have to use ShortcutManager and requestPinShortcut.  I got it working that way.  My reply below has a link to a question with a similar description and I put my code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question that led me to the answer.  It turned out you now need to use a pinned sshortcut.  I found an exclent demo on [AndroidAthority](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-nougat-oreo-static-dynamic-pinned-shortcuts-845686/) by Jessica Thornsby dated March 20, 2018 about implementing shortcuts on Nougat and Oreo that put it all together for me.
Please see [my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744184/how-to-create-shortcuts-on-android-o-when-targetting-less-than-it/) to a very similar question for my code.

I put a simple app that does nothing but install a shortcut for itself on your homepage on [github](https://github.com/bebop-001/CreateAppHomeShortcut).  It works for versions before and after Android 8.  Pre Android 8 uses the sendBroadcast method and after creats a pinned shortcut.